# Make sense using optional type protocol?

Tags: swift

I faced an issue which is pretty interesting for me. Probably you have better explanation and I would like share and discuss a little bit.

```
protocol HomeViewModelProtocol {
    func getText(postCode: String?)
}
```

---

ViewModel

```
HomeViewModel: HomeViewModelProtocol {
    func getText(postCode: String?) {
        guard let postCode = postCode else {
            return
        }
        postCode = someLocalVariable
    }
```

---

View

```
 postCodeTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postCodeFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


@objc private func postCodeFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    viewModel.getText(postCode: textField.text)
}
```

I am simply view and viewmodel. I want to pass optional type to viewmodel because i thought it would be better handling optional binding in view model ( view should not handle any logic ) am I right ?

But i feel like this is strange, I never see such approach before and probably i am making some mistake that is why I want to ask how can handle this `getText` better meaningful and elegance according to SOLID.

IMO everything is clear so please try to understand a little bit before closing the question if you think it is need debug details
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but the code inside getText makes no sense at all, then again maybe that is not relevant for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes no sense. The property `text` of `UITextField` – although declared as optional – is never nil. You can force unwrap it

```
@objc private func postCodeFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    viewModel.getText(postCode: textField.text!)
}
```

or in case of ***Exclamationmarkophobia*** use the nil-coalescing operator

```
@objc private func postCodeFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    viewModel.getText(postCode: textField.text ?? "")
}
```

and declare your protocol method non-optional.

```
protocol HomeViewModelProtocol {
    func getText(postCode: String)
}
```